# Create scroll layout like Instagram

Tags: android, scroll, instagram

I want to design a app which have a new feed screen like Instagram app.

If you have used Instagram you can see when you scroll up the toolbar will push up and replaced by header of feed. (Ok, I can do it which android support design) .

When you continue scroll, the header of the second feed will push up and replace the header of the first. I wonder how can they do that ? How can they detect when an item is over ?

This video demo how instagram app scroll :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ThzZlrKVY-g

Sorry about my grammar, Thank in advanced !!!

Comment: I come late, but you can check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33018788/how-can-i-set-a-listener-inside-a-recyclerview-header-decor/35574870#35574870

Comment: https://github.com/davideas/FlexibleAdapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're leaning towards Sticky Headers. There are many existing lightweight libraries out there that will make your life easier.

Check out [StickyHeadersRecycleView](https://github.com/timehop/sticky-headers-recyclerview) (Has a GIF to show how it works)

Alternate option, also a library.. [StickyHeader](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders)

Comment: Thank you so much. This is what I looking for .

Comment: were you able to implement loadmore with stickyheaders?

Answer (score 1):

You could try these steps. I've done it before using this steps.

1.) Create a ScrollView on your main layout with LinearLayout inside it
2.) Create a Fragment for a layout you need (Image and a comment section below)
3.) On your MainActivity Inflate the fragment inside the LinearLayout as much as you need(inflate the fragment for each images).

Comment: 1. Used Recycler. Linear layout will not save you. 2 The question is about sticky content: top of any current child MUST BE always on top of screen