# How can I set a listener inside a RecyclerView Header Decor?

Tags: android, header, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I implemented sticky headers in my RecyclerView, using [this library](https://github.com/edubarr/header-decor)

I want to add a clickable view inside the custom header, but when I set the listener in the

```
public void onBindHeaderViewHolder(HeaderHolder viewholderHeader, int position)
```

It ignores me, and the item of behind is clicked (background selector of the recyclerview list).

the onBindHeaderViewHolder is working, because of the setText I have in there. I want to know a way to do that the OnClickListener persists and the view receives it. (Without recycling if it is possible).

Comment: The sticky header you are seeing is not actually a View in the view hierarchy, it is only _drawn_ like one. That is why your touches go to the item the is behind it.

Comment: @Karakuri Ok, thanks Karakuri but, how can I bring the headers to the view hierarchy?

Comment: I only meant to explain the behavior you are seeing. I don't have any suggestions for a workaround at this point.

Comment: Thanks, it's something useful to search on..

Comment: Just a notification, to say that, StickyHeaders are now clickable, in my FlexibleAdapter project.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**EDIT of 29/03/2016:** Sticky Headers are now clickable using same listeners of the ViewHolder, not using anymore `ItemDecoration`. A `FrameLayout` is instead used.

**Answer:** I've worked on [header-decor](https://github.com/edubarr/header-decor) and on [sticky-headers-recyclerview](https://github.com/timehop/sticky-headers-recyclerview) and my conclusion is that, *ItemDecoration* should not be the way to implement a real good sticky headers, because what we have is just something drawn on the top and **is not a view(!)** so we cannot attach any listener on that thing and we cannot interact with that thing.

But... I was able, in my **[FlexibleAdapter](https://github.com/davideas/FlexibleAdapter)** project, to intercept the tap on the *sticky* header, now it is become an advanced solution for this functionality.

See my comments here:

- https://github.com/timehop/sticky-headers-recyclerview/issues/105#issuecomment-187144374
- https://github.com/davideas/FlexibleAdapter/issues/41

**Another very important note:**

The 2 projects, I mentioned on the top, make **heavy** use of cycle `for` statement: they draw, as a "decoration" many times on the top of the items (with `onDrawOver`), all the headers currently displayed. Not only, they put in a cache ALL the views and the reference to the positions **without recycling(!)** them.

You can imagine how much the memory increases and how much work the phone is making every time the list is scrolled of every pixel, with a huge battery consummation... Huh... I have removed all these things in the new `StickyHeaderHelper`.