# How to create ExpandableStickyListHeaders Recycler view android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to create sticky header recycler view with ability to expand and collapse sections without on header click i have found this this [library](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders)

but it uses listview and i want to use Recycler view because i want to use it as a list and Grid at the same time

did any body have made something like this
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Actually yes, just finished to add this new feature, and it should be also the way you would like. Check my [FlexibleAdapter](https://github.com/davideas/FlexibleAdapter) project, but, you should also read my answer here: [How can I set a listener inside a RecyclerView Header Decor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33018788/how-can-i-set-a-listener-inside-a-recyclerview-header-decor)

Comment: Thanks @Davidea i'll check it soon

Comment: Hey @Davidea i had took a look on your library, actually you have made awesome job but it missed few things to fill my requirement i want the sections to be expanded by clicking on the header and that's what your library missed as i understand so is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: Yes, it misses that :-( I want it too, and I am working on this piece. I suggest to follow the project so, as soon as it is ready you can update it. However, I need some tranquility time in order to complete it.

Comment: may i help you with this piece i will clone the project and we can have small conversation to work on same side maybe we can achieve this.

Comment: @Tony ok why not, I write here, because it's the only place until you don't open an issue on the page. First, read the issue #44, the user "farfromrefug" is already working on that too, the only thing is that, his adapter now is totally different but he's almost there to have this feature. However I don't want loose my work and I want the Adapter still based on the ArrayList, we might add a side Adapter that doesn't depends by the List as he is doing.

Comment: OK @Davidea today i will compare your code and his code and i will choose from where i can start