# How to Implement auto-scrolling for recyclerView when items are clicked like instagram?

Tags: android, instagram

Instagram have an auto-scrolling effect on their listviews when users clicks on a filter: See a video of it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R3VsKt5Ktao

So when the user clicks on an item, it helps the user to scroll one item to the left or right. How can this be archived with a recyclerView?

Comment: It's a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32720544/create-scroll-layout-like-instagram?rq=1

Comment: @ldd are you sure about duplicate ?